# std::function which returns any summable type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, openmp, std-function

My graph data structure for parallel algorithms has the following iterator method:

```
/**
 * Iterate in parallel over all nodes of the graph and call handler (lambda closure).
 */
void Graph::parallelForNodes(std::function<void(node)> handle) {
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (node v = 0; v < z; ++v) {
        // call here
        handle(v);
    }
}
```

I could have declared the `handle` function as a template parameter, but I thought the preferred way in C++11 is to use `std::function`.

Now I want to perform a parallel reduction using OpenMP with such an iterator. The return values of each call to `handle` are reduced to a sum. With function templates, this looks like:

```
template<typename L>
inline double Graph::parallelSumForNodes(L handle) {
    double sum = 0.0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
    for (node v = 0; v < z; ++v) {
        // call here
        if (exists[v]) {
            sum += handle(v);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

What is the equivalent using `std::function`?  Can I define the type of `handle` to return double or int (because the body of the function works with both).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but don't you just need `std::function<double(node)>`?

Comment: "but I thought the preferred way in C++11 is to use `std::function`." I had heated discussions about this with other people; I still think that should not be the preferred way *at all*.

Comment: `I could have declared the handle function as a template parameter, but I thought the preferred way in C++11 is to use std::function.` Don't let @R.MartinhoFernandes hear you say that...

Comment: FWIW, I agree with @R.MartinhoFernandes. I would keep `std::function` out if the interface here. I cannot see what you gain. You should use it if you need to store the handle.

Comment: ... or if you know the function type at compile-time, and don't want to be bundling your function definition into a header file for no reason. (When writing a library, I prefer to keep as much in the source files as I can.)

Comment: @juanchopanza If I declare it as `std::function<double(node)>` and pass something which returns an int, will it be automatically converted?

Comment: Yes, I think the function compatibility rules would allow to instantiate `std::function<double(T)>` from something returning an `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a two parameter member function, along the lines of `std::accumulate`?

```
template<typename Handle, typename Accumulator>
Accumulator Graph::parallelSumForNodes(Handle handle, Accumulator sum) 
{
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
    for (node v = 0; v < z; ++v) {
        // call here
        if (exists[v]) {
            sum += handle(v);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Note that this has the same caveat as `std::accumulate`: you have to be careful with the type of the accumulator you pass it.

Answer (score 1):

The following will allow you to pass a `handle` that returns an int or double (or other numeric type) to your function.  The function will return whatever type is returned by your handle.  You should be mindful of overflows however.

```
template<typename L>
inline L Graph::parallelSumForNodes(std::function<L(node)> handle) {
    L sum = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:sum)
    for (node v = 0; v < z; ++v) {
        // call here
        if (exists[v]) {
            sum += handle(v);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: `std::function` *with template parameters* is definite no-no. It makes life miserable for the clients of that function. (Just try it with *any* type whatsoever that isn't a `std::function` instance already).

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: I'd most likely agree that it doesn't provide a very user friendly interface.  However I think this does answer what the poster asked.

Answer (score 0):

Specify your template parameter to define the return type of std::function:

```
template<typename L>
inline L Graph::parallelSumForNodes(std::function<L(node)> handle)
{
    L sum();
    ...
    return( sum );
{
```